# The spring check box is not getting checked by default even when the value is true

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've a check box which has to be checked by default if the value coming from the controller is "true". I'm passing true from my controller and still the checkbox is not checked by default.(Though the value is displayed as true in the page source)

```
<td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;"><form:checkbox disabled="false" class="editable${ind}" 
path="myList[${Status.index}].include" value="${ind.myVal}"/> </td>
```

Not sure what is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator, store the value in a variable then use that value to apply css if checked

checkBoxValue == true ? checked : " "

Comment: Nothing seems to be working. I even tried giving checked= checked.